# How to apply drawerlayout on specific fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have the following problem:

I want to use navigation components and therefore I have only one activity (MainActivity) and several fragments.

I have two types of fragments: **authenticating stuff** and **the actual app**.
The **actual app** contains a **drawer layout** and the **auth stuff** should only be in **contraint layouts**.

But the problem is that the auth fragments also are showing the statusbar of the drawer layout.

I tried to hide the actionbar on these fragments calling `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();`
But this did not work and I got a black space at the top of the screen.

Is there any way to apply the drawerlayout to specific fragments or a general better approach to get this behavior?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private NavController navController;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

    private NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener listener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.firstFragment, R.id.secondFragment)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((_c, destination, _b) ->
        {
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.mainFragment ||
                    destination.getId() == R.id.loginFragment ||
                    destination.getId() == R.id.registerUserFragment)
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            else
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        });

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**my_nav.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.mioai.gamehub.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigateToSecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
            app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.mioai.gamehub.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.mioai.gamehub.MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_firstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/firstFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.mioai.gamehub.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_registerUserFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/registerUserFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/registerUserFragment"
        android:name="com.mioai.gamehub.RegisterUserFragment"
        android:label="fragment_register_user"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register_user" />

</navigation>
```